# Is one syntax a better choice for anonymous handlers?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, anonymous-function

Here are all the ways I know to handle an event. Any other syntax is just a playing with scope.

```
// one
Button.Click += delegate { /* do something */ };

// two
Button.Click += delegate(object s, EventArgs e) { /* do something */ };

// three
RoutedEventHandler handler = (s, e) => { /* do something */ };
Button.Click += handler;
Button.Click -= handler;

// four
Button.Click += (s, e) => { /* do something */ };
```

I understand numbers `one`/`two` are basically the same except for explicit arguments that can be used in the resulting logic. I also understand that number `three` allows me to add a handler *and* remove it, which can be very important. And, I understand number `four` is a simplified version of number two.

My question is more practical. **Between these two syntaxes, is there any reason to use one over the other or are they basically two ways to do the same thing?** And, how do you know?

```
// two
Button.Click += delegate(object s, EventArgs e) { /* do something */ };

// four
Button.Click += (s, e) => { /* do something */ };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Between these two syntaxes, is there any reason to use one over the other or are they basically two ways to do the same thing?

They effectively do the same thing.  In both cases, the compiler generates a method for you anonymously, creates the delegate, and assigns it.  The main advantage to the newer lambda syntax is that it is shorter.  The [Anonymous Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) suggests preferring the lambda syntax (syntax four) instead:

> C# 2.0 introduced anonymous methods and in C# 3.0 and later, lambda expressions supersede anonymous methods as the preferred way to write inline code.

Note that the anonymous method syntax (using `delegate`) does have one other feature not found in the lambda syntax.  If you're not going to use the arguments, you can leave them off, and write:

```
Button.Click += delegate { /* do something */ };
```

That being said, [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (syntax four) supports extra feature over anonymous methods, including better implicity typing, using the same syntax for creating expression trees, and async lambda support for C# 5.

Comment: Note that you can't detach the event handler like this.

Comment: @user1908061 You can detach the event handler using either syntax, but you have to just assign it to a delegate first.  That's not an advantage or disadvantage of either syntax.